# How to create a filename using variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am a complete novice coder. This is my first question on this forum.
I am trying to download an article using newspaper module in Python and save it as a text file. I want to generate name of the text file from the title of the article itself. I am doing the following steps -
I extract the title of article and text of the article.
While saving the article as a text file, I use the title to generate filename.
However the results are not consistent.
I am not able to generate a filename using a string variable which is assigned the title of the article. 
I get an empty file as a result in some cases, such as for the following url
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/icc-world-cup/rishabh- 
    pant-ambati-rayudu-named-indias-standbys-for-world-cup/articleshow/68921146.cms"

For the link given in this example, the title extracted is   India World Cup team 2019: Rishabh Pant, Ambati Rayudu named India's standbys for World Cup.
The filename generated is India World Cup team 2019. It is the text which is on left of character : . Also the file generated does have .txt extension

However the same code runs successfully for the following url
"https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/16/asia/dog-found-at-sea-thailand-intl/index.html"
The file is saved successfully as Dog found swimming 135 miles off the coast of Thailand.txt

The code is given below. What is causing this behavior? Do I need to remove special characters such as : from the heading before using it as a filename? If yes, how to do that? Will be  really grateful for your help.

```
import newspaper 
from newspaper import Article

url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/icc-world-cup/rishabh- 
pant-ambati-rayudu-named-indias-standbys-for-world-cup/articleshow/68921146.cms"

article = Article(url )
article.download()
article.parse()
text = article.text
filename = article.title
filename = filename+".txt"
f= open("{}".format(filename), "+w")    
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Comment: If you're on Windows, then `:` is probably an illegal character in a filename. You'll want to look up what characters are illegal on your filesystem and remove them. You should be able to find out how to do the removal pretty easily by searching other questions.

Comment: Is there any error output? Please, send the error :)

Comment: No error message comes

Comment: Thanks glibdud. I removed : using command filename1 = filename.replace(":", ""). And also modified the following f= open("{}".format(filename1), "+w", encoding="utf-8") With these two changes, the article is saved with correct file name.